# Mongoose Get Last X Values With Minimum Relative Time Difference

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get an exact number of DB entries which all have a minimum time difference to each other. E.g. a sensor writes to a database approx. every 1000ms, but I want to read e.g. 20 values with a minimum time diff. of 1 hour.

Currently, I'm reading with $gt, but this pulls 72000 (20x60mx60s) entries from the db.

Which I then filter:

```
  filterSensorHistory: (data, callback)->
    self = @
    data = _.sortBy(data, 'timestamp').reverse()
    lastEntry = moment(data[0].timestamp).add(5, self.timeUnit) #add 5 units to the last entry (for processing delay), works seconds & minutes
    data = data.filter (dataItem, index)->
      return false if lastEntry.diff(moment(dataItem.timestamp), self.timeUnit) <= 1 #if less than 1 time unit diff. reject
      lastEntry = moment(dataItem.timestamp)
      return true
    data = data.splice(0,HISTORY_LENGTH)
    data = data.map (dataItem)->
      return { x: moment(dataItem.timestamp).toDate(), y: dataItem.value }
    data.reverse()
    return callback null, data
```

I'm wondering if I can do this more efficient on a database level?

Mongo Version: 2.4.10

EDIT: Sample data

I want to query every second, minute or hour. E.g. every minute: `1, 12, 22, 32, 44 ...`. In this case I could basically `.skip(12)` but the sensor may also be off sometimes.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "value" : 54.1168212890625,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0853a7d7be048274809e"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:27:47.290Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "value" : 54.4702064708767,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0853a7d7be048274809d"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:27:47.078Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "value" : 54.4899286008879,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c084ba7d7be0482748097"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:27:39.745Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "value" : 54.5661574715879,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0844a7d7be0482748095"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:27:32.731Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "value" : 54.683723765302,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c083ea7d7be0482748093"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:27:26.213Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "value" : 54.7179478596223,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0837a7d7be0482748091"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:27:19.703Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "value" : 54.7588104883133,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0831a7d7be048274808f"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:27:13.171Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "value" : 54.5089721679688,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c082aa7d7be048274808d"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:27:06.898Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 9 */
{
    "value" : 54.8077643741843,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c082aa7d7be048274808c"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:27:06.634Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 10 */
{
    "value" : 54.825757605678,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0822a7d7be0482748086"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:26:58.975Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 11 */
{
    "value" : 54.8885850799935,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c081ca7d7be0482748084"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:26:52.003Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 12 */
{
    "value" : 54.9645862093469,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0815a7d7be0482748082"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:26:45.479Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 13 */
{
    "value" : 55.0455007725319,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c080fa7d7be0482748080"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:26:38.970Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 14 */
{
    "value" : 55.1649881938774,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0808a7d7be048274807e"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:26:32.423Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 15 */
{
    "value" : 55.2170605872354,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0801a7d7be048274807c"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:26:25.918Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 16 */
{
    "value" : 55.2759415120643,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07fba7d7be048274807a"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:26:19.400Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 17 */
{
    "value" : 55.3524623713558,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07f4a7d7be0482748078"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:26:12.890Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 18 */
{
    "value" : 55.470471603603,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07eea7d7be0482748076"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:26:06.363Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 19 */
{
    "value" : 55.5055806131762,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07e7a7d7be0482748074"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:25:59.807Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 20 */
{
    "value" : 55.5441593764087,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07e1a7d7be0482748072"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:25:53.306Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 21 */
{
    "value" : 55.5964646516023,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07daa7d7be0482748070"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:25:46.770Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 22 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07d4a7d7be048274806e"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:25:40.295Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 23 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07d4a7d7be048274806d"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:25:40.094Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 24 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07cba7d7be0482748066"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:25:31.653Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 25 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07c4a7d7be0482748063"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:25:24.774Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 26 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07bea7d7be048274805f"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:25:18.035Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 27 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07b7a7d7be048274805c"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:25:11.131Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 28 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07b0a7d7be0482748059"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:25:04.647Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 29 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07aaa7d7be0482748056"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:58.128Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 30 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c07a3a7d7be0482748052"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:51.421Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 31 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c079ca7d7be048274804f"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:44.758Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 32 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0796a7d7be048274804b"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:38.199Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 33 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c078fa7d7be0482748045"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:31.414Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 34 */
{
    "value" : 50.2505315620168,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c078ea7d7be0482748043"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:30.666Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 35 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0788a7d7be048274803e"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:24.421Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 36 */
{
    "value" : 51.7415246845763,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0787a7d7be048274803d"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:23.670Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 37 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0781a7d7be0482748038"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:17.948Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 38 */
{
    "value" : 53.2018025716146,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0781a7d7be0482748037"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:17.166Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 39 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c077aa7d7be0482748031"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:10.919Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 40 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c077aa7d7be0482748030"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:24:10.721Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 41 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c076ea7d7be0482748027"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:23:58.826Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 42 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0768a7d7be0482748024"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:23:52.295Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 43 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0761a7d7be0482748020"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:23:45.566Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 44 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c075aa7d7be048274801d"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:23:38.860Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 45 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0754a7d7be048274801a"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:23:32.275Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 46 */
{
    "value" : 55.6854248046875,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c074da7d7be0482748014"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:23:25.359Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 47 */
{
    "value" : 55.8850552677083,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c074da7d7be0482748013"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:23:25.157Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 48 */
{
    "value" : 55.8977314920825,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0745a7d7be048274800c"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:23:17.310Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 49 */
{
    "value" : 55.9236590972381,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0740a7d7be048274800a"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:23:12.143Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 50 */
{
    "value" : 55.9737888383277,
    "detectorType" : "humidity",
    "sensor" : ObjectId("588a427d617fff11d79b304a"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("595c0739a7d7be0482748006"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-07-04T21:23:05.427Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Since you do realize that doing this in code once the documents have been retrieved as a bad idea, then how about giving us a clearer picture of what your data looks like with samples of the data itself? If you just showed a couple of documents as input and the result you expect to achieve from that input, then you might just get some feedback from someone else who might view the problem differently. And then possibly actually give you a solution. Which was the point of asking, wasn't it? Make it easy for people to help.

Comment: And the best thing you can do is "update your MongoDB". 2.4 is not even officially supported anymore, plus it has known bugs (and problematic ones at that ) in addition to missing all the main feature changes over the last few years.

Comment: @NeilLunn provided some example data. Basically, the only important prop is the timestamp. 

I tried to update it, but it runs on a raspberry pi 3, `sudo apt-get install mongodb-server` tells me I already have the newest version available. I think this is because the support for a 32bit architecture has deprecated in later versions: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29208/mongodb-on-raspbian

Comment: Huh? Don't believe all you read. Official builds for 32-bit targets are make every day, and anything saying it's unsupported is completely wrong. As for *"someone building from source for you"* then it takes me a matter of seconds to find at least v3 binaries for raspberry pi http://andyfelong.com/2016/01/mongodb-3-0-9-binaries-for-raspberry-pi-2-jessie/ and there is no doubt someone out there with up to date builds as well. Actually look as compared to trusting a three year old post wit four votes.

Comment: It seems 3.x can be installed, but it looks a bit hacky: http://www.clarenceho.net/2015/12/building-mongodb-30x-for-arm-armv7l.html, so far I didn't run into any problems/limitations with 2.4.10.